# TSDF value when integrating around a thin surface

Tags: definition, 3d-reconstruction

While doing 3D-reconstruction, I was puzzled by the following scenario of computing the TSDF value of a voxel:

Suppose you have a thin piece of paper standing up and you take pictures around it. You want to predict the TSDF value of a voxel right behind it. When the paper is between the camera and the voxel, you get negative TSDF values. Yet when the voxel is between you and the paper (you are on the other side of the scene) you get positive TSDF values.

This just doesn't make sense since it seems that I should not integrate the voxel when I get negative TSDF values. But I cannot know that the object is a thin piece of paper, not a thick box before I rotate. But I looked at several papers and articles talking about this and they all have similar definitions.